# How shall I make the timer count the AVAudioPlayer.duration correctly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstimer

```
- (void)timerTickPlayer:(NSTimer*)timer 
{
    timeSec = 0;
    timeMin = 0;
    timeSec++;

    int displayTime = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:player.duration]    intValue];

    if (timeSec == displayTime)
    {
        timeSec = 0;
        [timer invalidate];
    }

    NSString* playerTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",timeSec];
    labelTime.text = playerTime;
}
```

Above is the method which I try to make the timer start counting form 00,
until it hits the duration.

But turns out the label will just show the duration for a moment, then change back to 00 again.

Where is the problem of my code/logic?

---

Here's the latest situation!

haha there's still a bug, seems to be getting solved.

[image: latest one]

Comment: If you need a current time playing you don't need timer to do the count, you can get the time directly from the AVAudioPlayer

Comment: For the error in the image, replace `[AVAudioPlayer` with instance call `[player`.

Answer (score 1):

With an AVPlayer, no need for a timer:

```
// timescale of 600 to report changes every 1/600th of a second (value taken from the doc of CMTimeScale)
CMTime interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 600)
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.timeObserver = [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval
                                                         queue:NULL
                                                    usingBlock:
                ^(CMTime time)
                {
                    int timeSec = (int)CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
                    NSString *playerTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", timeSec];
                    weakSelf.labelTime.text = playerTime;
                }];
```

---

Answering extra questions from ChiHsi Chung:

1. a weak self is required according to [documentation of `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserverforinterv?language=objc):

   > Important
   >
   > You should use a weak reference to self in the callback block to prevent creating a retain cycle.
2. you need to create your own `timeObserver` **strong** property of type `id` to store the return value of `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`. No, there is no type for it, because according to definition, `timeObserver` should be:

   > An opaque object that you pass as the argument to `removeTimeObserver:` to cancel observation.

Comment: Thanks! But may I ask some questions?

Comment: 1. Do I have to declare "self"? If do, why?

Comment: 2.Why can't I find a "timeObserver"? Isn't it a kind of type? Or I get something wrong about it?

Comment: @ChiHsiChung I've added the answers to the post.

Comment: Cœur please take a little view of my main question again, appreciate

Comment: I've tried your advise, there seemed to be some unexpected errors, which I tried to declare the "self" as a whole area var and bundle your solution into another function but still didn't work for both of them.

Comment: ok, I SOLVED THE FIRST ONE, about the second one, compiler told me that I'm using of undeclared identifier 'interval', so I need to declare that in somewhere?

Comment: @ChiHsiChung sorry, I forgot to define interval for you. I've updated my answer.